# extract first 4 letters from a string in matlab, when string may contain less than 4 letters

Tags: matlab

I want to keep the first four letters of each string in a cell array, or all the letters if the string has less than four. Using indexing fails, e.g.

```
tmpCell = {'asdf13' '245acva' 'a2d' '2'};
>> cellfun(@(x) x(1:4), tmpCell, 'uni', 0)

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in @(x)x(1:4)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my own problem now. Simply insert a `min()` as that will just choose either the first four letters or the whole string:

```
cellfun(@(x) x(1:min(4, length(x))), tmpCell, 'uni', 0)
```

or much better, as suggested by Luis Mendo:

```
cellfun(@(x) x(1:min(4, end)), tmpCell, 'uni', 0)
```

Comment: You can also use `cellfun(@(x) x(1:min(4, end)), tmpCell, 'uni', 0)`